# What happens if I interrupt the Linux kernel's make process?

Tags: linux, makefile, kernel

I downloaded the Linux kernel and started compiling it, so question has arisen since 
I'm building on an old laptop.

What if I hit Ctrl-C while `make`-ing and then run `make` again later; does it start the build 
from the beginning?

Comment: The purpose of `make` is to selectively perform only the tasks necessary to update all targets which are non-existent or whose inputs are more recent. I you don't issue `make clean` in the meantime, it won't rebuild up-to-date targets.

Comment: @flo totally wrong and frederic-hamidi maybe for completeness sake you could add it will have to recheck the dependencies (which also takes some time on slower machines) but won't recreate up to date targets.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The simple answer is as long as all the target files that make creates still exist and have a newer timestamp than the files they depend on they will not be rebuilt. Generally in order to have the behavior you're trying avoid occur you would have to issue a `make clean` command or something similar.

Comment: If so, then I can continue build at target I ctrlc'ed? as long as I don't modify files, they'll skipped right?

Comment: Even more importantly, it will re-do the target it was working on when it was interrupted (e.g., an object file). Make by default deletes the current target when interrupted to make sure half-written files will not compromise the following steps (see https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Interrupts.html).